# Stop windows 7 auto-update from creating backup files

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Since I run a windows 7 in virtualbox, I don't need to restore any service patches, just use the snapshot function, and the roll-back generated is pretty disk space costing, is it possible to disable that feature globally?;

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about the system restore functionality. And when you update, a restore point is created. You can find the directions on how to configure that, and turn it off if wanted, here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3187/disable-system-restore-in-windows-7/

It has screenshots and everything :)

Comment: Wait, you mean if I turn off system restore, it would never create any backup? (There's no other mechanism in use for restoring?)

Comment: System restore, I believe is automated protection against corruption, viruses, bad drivers, etc. Not a backup solution for your hard drive. I believe it wouldn't create these restore points when doing updates if it was turned off.

Alternative to that, you could actually specify a small amount of HD space to use for system restore and it would stay within that limit.